# using requests to login to a website that has javascript login form

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, post, python-requests

Let me preface by saying I have very little programming experience. I've learned a bunch in the last few days trying to write this program. I am running Python 2.7 on Windows 7 using PyCharm, requests, Beautiful Soup, and lxml.

I am trying to scrape data from a website that relies heavily on Javascript. I have two options:

1) The data I need is populated through Javascript and does not necessarily need a login. However I have not been able to figure how to get at this data. I've live monitored headers with live HTTP Headers chrome plugin and I think I've found the Javascript that does it but I'ts beyond my means to figure it out. Its a long bit of code, I'll post it if anyone is interested in taking a look.

or

2)On one of the main pages I found a series of ID numbers which I can use to generate URL's for each of the individual items I am analyzing. Problem is I have to be logged in to see these individual item pages. My code is as follows:

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

# Request a date from user
UDate = "06/22/2015"  # raw_input('Enter a date mm/dd/yyyy\n')

# Open TLSv1 Adapter (Whataver that means)
class MyAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)

# Begin a requests session. Every get from here on out will use TLSv1 Protocol
import requests

payload = {
    'LogName': 'xxxxxxxx',
    'LogPass': 'xxxxxxxx'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://xxxx.xxx', MyAdapter())

# Login with post and Request source code from main page.
log = s.post('LoginURL', data=payload)
print log.text

result = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content)
print soup
```

Neither the post or the get show me a logged in website. The logform id's from the HTML source code look like this:

```
<div id="DivLogForm">
        <label for="BadText"><div id="BadText" class="BadText" style="display:none" tabindex="-2">User Name or Password is Invalid</div></label>

        <div class="LogLabel">
            <label for="LogName" > User Name&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input tabindex="0" id="LogName" class="LogInput" value="" />
        </div>
        <div  class="LogLabel">
            <label for="LogPass" >User Password&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input  tabindex="0"id="LogPass" type="password" class="LogInput" value="" />
        </div>
```

So I'm passing LogName and LogPass with the post.

There is also a logform.js with this bit of code

```
$("#LogButton").click(function()
        {   //$('#divLogForm').hide();
            //$('#divLoading').show();  

           var uName = $("#LogName").val();
           var uPass = $("#LogPass").val();
           var url = "/index.cfm";
           $.post(url, {ZACTION:'AJAX',ZMETHOD:'LOGIN',func:'LOGIN',USERNAME:uName, USERPASS:uPass}, 
                  function(data){if (data.isOk =="YES"){location.href="/index.cfm";}
                                  else {$('.BadText').show(); $('#BadText').focus();};
                                 },"json");
        });
```

The LoginURL in my code is taken from the var url in this script. I have tried using USERNAME & USERPASS and I have tried uName and uPass with my post but these didnt work either.

Not sure how to move forward here. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last bit of javascript you posted gives a clue as to why your login POST request isn't working.

According to the javascript, you should be sending a dictionary that looks like the following with your login POST:

```
{
    'ZACTION': 'AJAX',
    'ZMETHOD': 'LOGIN',
    'func': 'LOGIN',
    'USERNAME': '<enter username>',
    'USERPASS': '<enter password>'
},
```

Comment: That works beautifully. Seems obvious now. Thanks a bunch. I got a new problem now (such is the nature of coding Im starting to realize): all my gets are redirected to an announcements page instead of the page with the content im after...

Comment: What kind of announcements? You should visit those pages on a browser and see what is actually sent in the requests for those pages. It could be that you're missing something in the headers.

Comment: Its general announcements about the websites policy changes. I get the same redirect in the browser. It just started, wasn't happening yesterday.